# Scale factor Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

How to make correct design measurements for all resolutions in windows phone?
As per Microsoft [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx) base screen size is 800x400 (853x400) but in real life it doesnt looks like true.

I did design in base resolution 853x400

Code

```
  <Image Width="160" Height="90" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"/>
```

What I expect to see on different emulators

- WVGA 4 inch - x1 = 160x90
- 720p 4.7 inch - x1.5 = 240x135
- 1080p 5.5 inch - x2.25 = 360x203

What I see

- WVGA 4 inch - x1.2 = 192x108
- 720p 4.7 inch - x1.8 = 288x162
- 1080p 5.5 inch - x2.4 = 384x216

From this base resolution is 800x450?

When testing margins - I got more or less same results:

Code

```
  <Grid Margin="14, 0, 0, 0"/>
```

- WVGA 4 inch - x1.214 = 17px
- 720p 4.7 inch - x1.79 = 25px
- 1080p 5.5 inch - x2.43 = 34px

But fonts drawing is different
-+
Code

```
  <Style x:Key="TitleStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiLight" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Results

- WVGA 4 inch - x0.93 = 26px
- 720p 4.7 inch - x1.32 = 37px
- 1080p 5.5 inch - x1.75 = 49px

What I should do? How to work with different resolutions correctly?

Comment: Take a look at the [RawPixelsPerViewPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.rawpixelsperviewpixel.aspx) property. You can get it like this `DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel` and it should be the correct multiplier.

Comment: Consider removing the WP7 and WP8 tags, since this post is specific to WP 8.1 XAML apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @yasen says, RawPixelPerViewPixel is what you want. The 480px baseline resolution is specific to Silverlight applications, whereas you are building a Universal (XAML) application. More information about this can be found in [this recorded presentation from //build](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-541). You can skip forward to 48:35 if you just want to know about the change from WP8 to 8.1